# Redirecting to another component's section in Angular

Tags: angular, anchor, router

I am trying to redirect from component A to component B's section by using router and anchor tag in Angular. I have managed to redirect the URL with the anchor at the back such as:
http://localhost:4200/home#finished

However, it does not scroll down to the section. I have put the below options in app.module but it still does not work. Can I know what can I do to make it scroll down to the section?

```
{
      anchorScrolling: 'enabled',
      onSameUrlNavigation: 'reload',
    }
```

the code in component A:

```
<button (click)="toFinished()"</button>

toFinished(){
    this.router.navigate(['/home'], {fragment:'finished'});
  }
```

code in component B:

```
<div id="finished">...</div>
```

Comment: id="#finished" ?? 

i'm not too familiar with angular. merely suggesting the # based on other frameworks

Answer (score 0):

You can use vanilla Javascript to scroll to the element:

```
const element = document.getElementById('finished');
if (element) {
    element.scrollIntoView();
}
```